# Live Paypal Payment Goes Through, Then Is Immediately Reversed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I have an app that ends with a chained adaptive payment on PayPal. Originally, I was having issues passing the credentials through, but I figured that out, and it now makes it all the way through the payment process...however, once I make the payment, it tells (the buyer) that the payment could not go through, and to return to the website.

If you login to paypal, both the seller and buyer's account shows the money being paid, then reversed, and paypal charging the seller a fee for the return. I double checked the IPN address that is set in the paypal selling tools, and had to correct it, because it was still pointing to my test site... However, even after changing it the same error occurs.

The log files merely say:
(Note: I removed a lot of personal information, or numbers I am unsure if they are 'sensitive' but did not change any of the message information)

`Started POST "/payment_notifications" for (IP_ADDRESS) at 2014-06-06 07:34:41 +0000
Processing by PaymentNotificationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"transaction"=>{"1"=>{".pending_reason"=>"NONE", ".paymentType"=>"SERVICE", ".amount"=>"USD 0.90", ".is_primary_receiver"=>"false", ".receiver"=>"(SENSITIVE INFO)"}, "0"=>{".id_for_sender_txn"=>"7E898850FR4486648", ".receiver"=>"(SENSITIVE INFO)", ".is_primary_receiver"=>"true", ".id"=>"5WG93840R5745335B", ".status"=>"Reversed", ".paymentType"=>"SERVICE", ".status_for_sender_txn"=>"Reversed", ".pending_reason"=>"NONE", ".amount"=>"USD 1.00"}}, "payment_request_date"=>"Fri Jun 06 00:33:59 PDT 2014", "return_url"=>"(SENSITIVE INFO)", "fees_payer"=>"PRIMARYRECEIVER", "ipn_notification_url"=>"http://(SENSITIVE INFO)/payment_notifications", "sender_email"=>"(SENSITIVE INFO)", "verify_sign"=>"(SENSITIVE INFO)", "cancel_url"=>"http://(SENSITIVE INFO).com/my-studio", "reason_code"=>"Unknown", "pay_key"=>"AP-9P552894H6794962K", "action_type"=>"PAY", "expiration_date"=>"Fri Jun 06 00:34:22 PDT 2014", "transaction_type"=>"Adjustment", "status"=>"ERROR", "log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction"=>"false", "charset"=>"windows-1252", "notify_version"=>"UNVERSIONED", "reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error"=>"false"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a new `PaymentDetailsRequest` with the `pay_key` to see the payment details.
Maybe you'll find something useful there.

In our case, when the `reason_code` was set to `Unknown` one of the receivers in the chained
payment was the reason why everything got reversed. So you may check all receivers.